# Using dgram module into browser application

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm building a web application that use a module that require the dgram module of nodejs, I have to run this application in a browser, but when I try to build it with webpack, it return me errors on the dgram module:

ERROR in C:/Users/Sibo//coap/lib/agent.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'dgram' in C:\Users\Sibo\node_modules\coap\lib
@ C:/Users/Sibo//coap/lib/agent.js 12:22-38

ERROR in C:/Users/Sibo//coap/lib/server.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'dgram' in C:\Users\Sibo\node_modules\coap\lib
@ C:/Users/Sibo//coap/lib/server.js 11:22-38

Do you know a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use dgram in browser for normal sites. It is possible however for Chrome Apps using [chrome-dgram](https://github.com/feross/chrome-dgram).

The only solution to error you're getting is adding `node` configuration to your Webpack config:

```
node: {
  dgram: 'empty'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

dgram is basically a node.js core module, and hence you wont be able to use this on browser end.

However, there is a browser equivalent verion of drag module available. See if that is useful for you. If useful, try this

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    dgram: "dgram-browserify"
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, can you tell me please in which file I have to insert the resolve object?